# How to extract the maximum value from a N-ary tree using recursion in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, tree, max

I am trying to find a way to keep track of the maximum value in my code. Right now I know that my for-loop looks at every node in my tree and compares it to the last max. But my issue is as the function calls are popped off the stack I end up only evaluating the first set of children and my max is chosen from those rather than the whole tree. The nodes can have any number of children and a payload.

```
public static Integer max(TreeNode<Integer> root) {

    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int maximum = root.payload;

    if (root != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) {
            if (root.children.get(i).payload > maximum) {
                maximum = root.children.get(i).payload;
            }
            max(root.children.get(i));
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

tree example:

```
                    1
         4          6        7
         9               10  11  12
```

Max:12
My Max:7

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public ArrayList<TreeNode<T>> children;
    public T payload;
}
```

Comment: Set the maximun static variable outside the max method or add the maximun parameter to the max method

Comment: I have constraints that don't allow for a static variable outside the max method. Is there a way to do it without changing the maximum parameters?

Comment: show me your TreeNode class, plz

Comment: I just added the TreeNode class above

Comment: You should review the input value for the tree node or try to print it, I tried and the answers all worked well

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused too. I keep getting null pointer exceptions. I think it might be evaluating the children.size() to null ... somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
    public static Integer max(TreeNode<Integer> root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        } 

        if (root.children == null) {
                return null;
        }

        int maximum = root.payload;
        for (int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) {
            if (root.children.get(i).payload > maximum) {
                maximum = root.children.get(i).payload;
            }
            Integer childsMaximun = max(root.children.get(i));
            if ((childsMaximun != null) && (childsMaximun > maximum)){
              maximum = childsMaximun;
            }
        }
        return maximum;
    }
```

Comment: When I try it that way I am getting a null pointer exception on the for-loop line. Also three more on the "Integer childMaximum = max(root.children.get(i));" line. Is this an issue with the  recursive call? Or the for-loop?

Comment: Just need to validate the children Array is not null. I updated the post. @TexasToots. Also you should implement a better TreeNode that has more validations.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int maximum(TreeNode<Integer> t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int max = t.payload;
    List<TreeNode<Integer>> children = t.children;

    if (children != null && children.size() > 0) {
        for (TreeNode<Integer> e: children) {
            // recursive call here
            int maxNext = maximum(e);
            if (maxNext > max) max = maxNext;
        }
    } 

    return max;
}
```

Your solution is not recursive. You are only checking the `max` in the `children` of `root`, not deeper than that.

You should traverse through all the `children` and keep on updating `max`. I have done it using recursion, there can be many other ways to traverse a tree.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception at the start of the if statement and at the int maxNext line.

Comment: My test requires me to return null if root is null... but that edit does fix the null pointer exception I was getting. Thanks

Comment: You can modify the code as you seem fit for your requirements.

Comment: I am just unclear on why when I write `if (root == null) return -1;` I no longer get a null pointer exception. But when I write `if (root == null) return null;` in that same line of code I get a null pointer exception?

Comment: That is because of recursive calls. If you return null, the value will be used in its previous call and that’ll give you an NPE. Ideally for getting the max, you should be returning -1 (assuming the the tree only has positive values).

Comment: Okay, I will keep working on a way to make this work. Thank you for being so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add contructor to initialize an ArrayList, try my TreeNode class:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
public T payload;
public List<TreeNode<T>> children;

public TreeNode(T payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addChildren(T... childs){
    for (T child: childs){
        TreeNode<T> node = new TreeNode<>(child);
        children.add(node);
    }
}
public void addChildren(TreeNode<T>... childs){
    for (TreeNode<T> child: childs){
        children.add(child);
    }
}

public static TreeNode<Integer> DEFAULT(){


    TreeNode<Integer> root7 = new TreeNode<>(7);
    root7.addChildren(10,11,12);

    TreeNode<Integer> root6 = new TreeNode<>(6);

    TreeNode<Integer> root4 = new TreeNode<>(4);
    root4.addChildren(9);

    TreeNode<Integer> root1 = new TreeNode<>(1);

    root1.addChildren(root7, root6, root4);

    return root1;
    }
}
```